# Dynamic Cache Manifest for app

Tags: php, iphone, manifest, offlineapps, offline-caching

There is a lot of questions about this subject, but I can't really find anything usefull to my problem. I'm using the HTML5 cache manifest on a web app. The web app is made in wordpress and it's also made like a Native app on iPhone.

The problem is, that I would like to get the native app run when fly mode is enabled or you just don't have a connection to the internet. Right now I'm caching all the images, libaries and the php templates, and that works fine.

The problem is, that I would like it to cach or save the content of the pages. It would be possible and easy if all the pages was static HTML, but all my content is dynamic.

Anyone who knows a way to do this?

I'm using the Patrick Chia's wordpress plugin to make the cache manifest file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use caching for the pages and something like [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for the data. Then use Javascript to merge the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell a little bit more, or give an example?